# how do I access specific array element that is part of a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, logic

```
var array1 = [1,2,3]
var array2 = [3,4,5]
var array3 = [5,6,7]
var dictionaryArray1 = [1: array1, 2:array2, 3:array3]
var array4 = dictionaryArray1[1][0]
```

this doesn't work...
the "[0]" is me trying to access the first element inside array1.
any idea how to do this?

Comment: need more info for this... what element are you trying to get out of the dictionary array.. also for array4 when you add that second [] it is no longer an array but that specific element in array 1

Comment: If you have a syntax error that you don't understand, then try to split the expression into simpler expressions, in your case that could be `let foo = dictionaryArray1[1] ; let bar = foo[0]`. Cmd-click on `foo` then reveals that it has the type `[Int]?`, where the question mark shows that it is an optional.